# LNK1104 cannot open file boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to embed python into my C++ code using boost, and I have had nothing but trouble the whole time. I have included `"boost\python.hpp"` and there is no error about including it, and this is the code I am trying to run:

```
FILE* file;
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
Py_Initialize();
PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
file = fopen("VAX.py", "r");
PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "VAX.py");
Py_Finalize();
```

And I get the following error: `LNK1104 cannot open file boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` I have tried what others have suggested on similar questions with no avail, like the fact that I was using 64 bit Python with 32 bit boost libraries so I downgraded to Python 32 bit (2.7) and I still get the same error.

Or is there anything better besides boost to embed python into c++?

Comment: You can't use 32 bit boost with a 64 bit application or vise versa. If that is not the problem have you set the linker paths so that Visual Studio can find the boost libraries?

Comment: ***LNK1104 cannot open file boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib*** Means this library is not found, is the wrong 32 / 64 bit (must match your application) or is corrupt.

Comment: I did set the linker paths, and yes everything is 32 bit

Comment: Does that file `boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` exist in the path you added to your linker paths?

Comment: Interestingly, it has a file named `boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` but not `boost_python-vc140-mt-1_61.lib`